# App crashes when hits break point - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, breakpoints

I run the app and it works fine. It does everything I want it to do. When I click on a button, it crashes with the error, " thread 1 exc_breakpoint (code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode=0x0)"

Things i have tried:

- Cleaning the app
- Building the app
- Testing the app
- Removing all @IBOutlets

Here is the @IBAction I am clicking

```
@IBAction func optionButton(sender: AnyObject) {
       let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "You Disliked The Displayed Image", message: "Take Your Own Or Choose From Your Library", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
    }

    let takePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Picture", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        var takeImage = UIImagePickerController()
        takeImage.delegate = self
        takeImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        takeImage.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(takeImage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    let choosePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose From Camera Roll", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        var image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    actionSheetController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as UIView; 
    //Present the AlertController
    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)



    actionSheetController.addAction(choosePictureAction)
    actionSheetController.addAction(takePictureAction)
    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
}
```

Error occurs on line where it says:

```
actionSheetController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as UIView;
```

Here is my viewDidLoad method:

var allImages = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, image11, image12, image13, image14]

```
    var imageCount: Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allImages.count)))
    }

    switch imageCount {
    case 1:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4183")
    case 2:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4323")
    case 3:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4325")
    case 4:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4327")
    case 5:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4330")
    case 6:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4331")
    case 7:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4335")
    case 8:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4338")
    case 9:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4394")
    case 10:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4400")
    case 11:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4479")
    case 12:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4508")
    case 13:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4772")
    case 14:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_4776")
    default:
        println("didn't set image")
    }
```

I have never seen this breaking point error. Can anyone help and explain to me why this error has occurred? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @BryanChen what do I change in my code?

Comment: @BryanChen "exc_breakpoint" isn't the same as "breakpoint". His app is definitely crashing.

Comment: Hm... I've run your `optionButton:` code and it works for me. Why do you think that code in your `viewDidLoad:` is related?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I researched about this crash. Some of the answers tell us to check your code in the viewDidLoad and remove all          IBOutlets.